# What is "<:" in C?

Tags: c, operators, xmos

I'm troubleshooting some simple tutorial code for XMOS processors and I've come across an operator that I've never seen before in C.  What does `<:` do?  As it is used here, it appears to set a variable high or low, but why not just use `=`?

```
void flashing_led_task1(port p,int delay_in_ms){
    while(1){
        p<:0;
        delay_milliseconds(delay_in_ms);
        p<:1;
        delay_milliseconds(delay_in_ms);
    }
}
```

This is just a generic question that I could not find googling or searching stack exchange.

Comment: That's not a standard C operator. Perhaps the language you're programming is *similar* to C, but not actually C? Or perhaps it goes through a preprocessor which handles the non-C bits?

Comment: XMOS is using their own "XC" language, not C. Now you should be able to find it.

Comment: This does not appear to be C, but if it was C (at least since C99), `<:` outside a string or character literal would be a *digraph* token that behaves the same as the `[` token except when it is "stringized".

Comment: For reference: https://www.xmos.ai/download/AN10018:-A-flashing-LEDs-example(1.0.0rc4).pdf

Comment: The document I linked to (and the likely origin of your code) even says, *"The <: operator drives a value on a port."*.  Its right there in the docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Standard C, the `<:` and `:>` symbols are [digraphs](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.6).  Except for spelling, `<:` is equivalent to `[` and `:>` is equivalent to `]`.

However, when those symbols are translated in your code (and the code reformatted for readability, including adding a space between `void` and the function name, and between `port` and `p`, and between `int` and `delay_in_ms`), you end up with:

```
void flashing_led_task1(port p, int delay_in_ms)
{
    while (1)
    {
        p[0;
        delay_milliseconds(delay_in_ms);
        p[1;
        delay_milliseconds(delay_in_ms);
    }
}
```

And that doesn't make much sense.  So, you may have to look hard at the manual for the C compiler on your system to find out what it means.  Or it might just be that your copy'n'paste operations, which (I hypothesize) omitted some spaces, also omitted the `:>` symbols or other key bits of the code fragment.

With the [hint about XC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76094088/what-is-in-c#comment134198353_76094088) from [Eugene Sh.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4253229/eugene-sh), p13 of the [XC Manual](https://www.xmos.ai/download/Programming-XC-on-XMOS-Devices(X9577A).pdf) (the start of chapter 2) has a diagram with:

- `<:` used for output
- `:>` used for input

The code on p14 shows these operators in use.

XC is not the same as C, though it is closely related.